# How to replace .prevAll() and .addBack() with plain javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.star', function () {
  $(this).prevAll().addBack().addClass('full');
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.star', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('full');
});
```

I would like to create similar functions with native javaScript. 
The content is dynamically rendered.

How can I target siblings elements on `mouseover`, and on `mouseout`, how can I  remove the class from just one element out of all - the one that is clicked.

Here's what I've tried:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
    if (target.matches('.star')) {
      target.classList.remove('full');
    }
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
    if (target.matches('.star')) {
      target.classList.add('full');
      // This one removes the class for ALL .star elements.
    }
  }
}, false);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-vote="1" class="star">Star</div>
<div data-vote="2" class="star">Star</div>
<div data-vote="3" class="star">Star</div>
<div data-vote="4" class="star">Star</div>
<div data-vote="5" class="star">Star</div>
```

[Jsfiddle with what I have tried](https://jsfiddle.net/gsavb168/1/).

[Jsfiddle with jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/b5863ko4/1/) - Existing solution - I'm trying to copy this into native javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseout", function({ target }) {
    if (target.matches('.star')) {
      target.classList.remove('full');
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseover", function({ target }) {
    if (target.matches('.star')) {
      addClassToPrevSiblings(target, 'full');
    }
}, false);

function addClassToPrevSiblings(elem, classToAdd) {
  while (elem) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
      elem.classList.add(classToAdd);
    }
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
  }
}
```

For both events I am just checking if their target is a star element. When it is a `mouseout` event I loop through [previous siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) and the element itself to add the `full` class.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wfthv0sL/) is the working example on jsFiddle.

Comment: While your code in the linked JS Fiddle may answer the question, your question - and a full explanation of how it works - should be included here, in your answer. Linking to an external demo is a useful bonus, and is appreciated, but it does not circumvent the need for this answer to be able to stand alone (in the event that JS Fiddle falls over, removes content or otherwise dies).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didnt know this rule. Edited the answer to comply with it.

Comment: @MarcosLuis, thank you very much! Much appreciated. This was spot on.